# executing remote psexec while logged on as SYSTEM

Tags: windows, authorization, psexec

Step 1). log into local windows xp (sp3) machine as system account

Step 2). execute psexec test as follows on remote xp (sp3) machine

`psexec \\nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn ipconfig /all`

RESULT:

```
    Couldn't access nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn

    Access is denied.
```

Question: Why?

I am logged on as windows System user, the system user is all powerfull
i should be able to do anything, with no access restrictions at all

This doesnt work either

psexec \\nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn -s ipconfig /all

why doesnt being logged onto a local xp machine as SYSTEM give me the power to run
anything on a remote machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SYSTEM account is all powerfull when it comes to the local system, but not on remote systems. Use -u to specify a username...

Comment: yeah, i didnt want to that :-(

Comment: i need a garuanteed way to remotely acces any machine on a windows network without knowing any passwords before hand. and get the authorityy to run processes on them. i do not want to have to sit at each machine in turn and i dont want to keep a record of all passwords and i cannot rely on a having a standrad admin account on all the machines. is there no way at all to do this? there has to be a way...

Comment: @user423199: In a domain setup you would have domain admins, but I'm guessing this is a normal workgroup setup?